# what does ": ?" mean in javascript source codes

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

what does something like this means?

```
_scrollViewRef: (null: ?ScrollView)
```

> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L439

or this :

```
watchID = (null: ?number);
```

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_geolocation.htm

my confusion is in this part   " **: ?** "
how does these codes works ?
what does this mean?

Comment: @IanBrindley are you sure about it? check again the syntax :)

Comment: LOL Should't have logged on over xmax xD

Comment: OK, [here](https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/18/Typecasts.html) it is. It is a Flow typecast expression, which will check that `<expr>` is of `<type>`. It is not part of JavaScript syntax. It is from [Flow](https://flowtype.org/), which basically is a type checker for JS.